# Expo Google Authentication doesn't work on production

Tags: expo

I implemented Expo Authentication on my app, following the code from the doc https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/#google.

On local with the Expo client its working fine, in the IOS simulator and also in the web browser but when I build the app (*expo build android*) and try on my Android phone, the Google popup comes, I put my id and it send me back to the login page but NOTHING happen.

I put some alert to understand what was going on but I dont even get any, useEffect doesn't fire, *responseGoogle* doesnt seem to change.

```
const [requestGoogle, responseGoogle, promptAsyncGoogle] =
    Google.useAuthRequest({
      expoClientId:
        "my_id",
      androidClientId:
        "my_id,
      webClientId:
        "my_id",
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    alert("useEffect fired (Google)");
    if (responseGoogle?.type === "success") {

      const { authentication } = responseGoogle;
       
      // success
      alert("success : "+JSON.stringify(responseGoogle));
      
      // some code to check and log the user... 

    } else {
      alert('no success : '+JSON.stringify(responseGoogle));
    }
  }, [responseGoogle]);
```

Any idea ?

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue ? seems like expo doesn't provide good documentation

Comment: @ParthNandaniya no I went with https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/, you can see my solution below

Answer (score 3):

Apparently its a know bug so here is not the answer but an alternative with  expo-google-sign-in :

```
 import * as GoogleSignIn from "expo-google-sign-in";
 async function loginWithGoogle() {    
    try {
      await GoogleSignIn.askForPlayServicesAsync();
      const { type, user } = await GoogleSignIn.signInAsync();
      if (type === "success") {
        alert(JSON.stringify(user));
      }
    } catch ({ message }) {
      toast.show("Erreur:" + message);
      alert("login: Error:" + message);
    }
  }
```

Comment: But does this work in expo go ?

Comment: Not in 2022 :/ I didn't found any solution theses days and there is also a problem with Facebook.

Comment: So how would you approach this? I've tried authsession and app-auth from expo. None of them work in production. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I dont know, we are on the same boat, I posted on /r/reactnative and I got no answer, this question is also about this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70019284/expo-auth-session-two-app-options-on-return-to-app but same, no help.

Comment: There got to be a way out of it!

Comment: I posted on Discord's Expo, no one seem to care about this problem so I think I will eject my app and look at the regular RN solutions.

Comment: I tried that many times over! Couldn't make it work as well!

Comment: Did you try expo-auth-sessions with firebase? @Tahola

Comment: No I dont want to use Firebase.

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess so I found a solution, Its come from AndroidManifest.xml , it contain too many android:scheme, you have to remove the extra ones but for accessing this file you will need to do an expo eject (going bare workflow).

Comment: Thanks for updating on it. What do you use for backend services? AWS? @Tahola

Answer (score 0):

You don't call `WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();` in you code example.
It need call after imports:

```
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
```

Now I have this problem with expo sdk 48.
But I change libs version to:

```
"expo": "~47.0.13"
"expo-auth-session": "~3.8.0",
```

And now it work on dev and production.
Token located in `responseGoogle.params.access_token` or `responseGoogle.authentication.accessToken`

Comment: Thank you but my question is almost 18 months old, the api changed a lot since then, I dont think your answer is relevant here.